# How can I see interest_by_country while collecting Google Trends data with gtrendsR()

Tags: r, google-trends, gtrendsr

I am trying to download Google Search Trends on various keywords by using the `gtrendsR` package. However, when I give `"TR"` to the `geo` argument I am receiving only interest by city series. How can I get hit values in country level?

Here is my code:

```
trends <- gtrends(
  c("Audi", "BMW+BMV", "Chevrolet+şevrole", "Citroen", "Dacia"), 
  geo = c("TR"), time = paste("2015-10-01", current.date, sep = " " )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no data to display as you have restricted your Country to "TR". You could either add extra countries or try geo = "all" to get every country.